# Building SharpKeeper (ZooKeeper Client for .NET)

Tags: building, apache-zookeeper, pre-build-event

I've been looking for .NET version of the ZooKeeper client and I found one.
https://github.com/ewhauser/zookeeper/tree/trunk/src/dotnet/SharpKeeper/

I was so thrilled and downloaded the source files to build a client assembly file.
but when I opened up the solution file and tried to build them all, I found some files were missing which should have been under "Generated" namespace/folder.

of course, there's no folder named "Generated" on the github repository.
I don't know what's going on.

the name of the folder, which is "Generated", looks like that I should add some build event to the solution. but nowhere I could see any description saying what kind of stuff I need to have or do.

anybody ever built the same thing? 
I need your hands. 
thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ZooKeeper's jute code generator supports csharp generation. You need to run this to generate the missing files:

org.apache.jute.compiler.generated.Rcc

See Zk's toplevel build.xml for details on how to do this.

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't know that I should ant build them first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just build the java project using ant, and it will create the missing C# files in the generated folder. here are step by step.
1) download ant, and extract it into a folder.
2) open command line and navigate to the folder in kafka where build.xml is.
3) run the following command [path to ant]\ant.bat

That's it now the C# files will be there.